# jQuery not loading with my HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my simple HTML :
tesJQUERY.html

```
<html>
   <head>
     <title>Tes JQuery</title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="tes.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div >
        hahaha
       </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

my simple jQuery script : 
tes.js

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').hide();
});
```

I have connected them and it was displayed in my dreamweaver..but not working...

Comment: You haven't loaded jQuery's library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include external jquery in your html file either by downloading it or using online version like:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

or

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can download the latest versions of jquery from below URL:

```
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js (compressed, for production)

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js (uncompressed, for debugging)
```

Comment: how to download the offline version ?

Comment: Please go to the URL to download the latest version of jquery and save them to the file system.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include jQuery like this (*before including your `tes.js`*)

```
<html> 
<head><title>Tes JQuery</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="tes.js"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 
   <div> hahaha </div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, can i just download the file instead using link to the jquery reference ?

Comment: @JohanSurya Yes, you can download and use it offline.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Tes JQuery</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tes.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div >
    :D :D :D
</div>
</body>
</html>
```